# SetFocus not working

Tags: knockout.js

In my knockout app I am trying to use setFocus like this

```
<div class="row" data-bind="visible: $root.inOwnerShipChangingMode">
        <div class="medium-12 columns">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter user name to give ownership (trans)" data-bind="autoComplete: { selected: $root.newOwnerForLocationId, options: observableArrayOfUsersWhoCanBecomeOwners}, hasFocus: true" />
        </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work. The element as you can see is hidden depending upon *$root.inOwnerShipChangingMode*. I have tried putting it out of the visible binding, still doesn't work.

My knockout version is 3.3.0.

Comment: I don´t know what are you trying to achieve. You want to set focus on input, and it is not working? Or the content is not even visible? We cannot help you like that.

Comment: [hasFocus won't set focus if element is hidden](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/355)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried binding `hasFocus` to an observable value - or even just a function which returns `true`? `hasFocus` is a two-way binding so it *might* not work with something which doesn't work in both directions.

Also, if the bound <input/> element isn't visible at the time of binding then the browser will probably refuse to grant it the focus. When you later set the parent <div> to be visible, your <input/> won't be given the focus because there's no reason for `hasFocus` to be re-bound - it still has the same values/properties/attributes as when it was loaded and nothing has changed in this respect.

So I'd suggest assigning an observable to `hasFocus`, even if the value of this never changes.